# Handling dates with Asp.Net MVC and KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I recently started working with KnockoutJs and quickly realized using the default `Json(myModelWithADate)` resulted in the default json encoding of `\/Date(-62135578800000)\/`  With a bit of research I located four potential ways to handle the display of my dates in dom elements.

*1) Create a binding that handles the conversion from the Json date to the format you desire*

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var jsonDate = valueAccessor();
        var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        var ret = value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
        element.innerHTML = ret;
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

    }
};
```

Usage

```
<td data-bind="date: DueDate">
</td>
```

*2) Return “strings” from your Controller*

```
return Json(new {MyDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()});
```

*3) Use the JSON.NET to specify a Date Time format seen over at [james.newtonking.com](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx)*

Example

```
string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
// {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"}
```

*4) use JSON.parse to handle your dates as seen in this [stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5954367/181776)*

```
JSON.parse(jsonText, function(key, value) {
    // Check for the /Date(x)/ pattern
    var match = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//.exec(value);
    if (match) {
        var date = new Date(+match[1]); // Convert the ticks to a Date object
        return humanReadable(date); // Format the date how you want it
    }

    // Not a date, so return the original value
    return value;
});
```

They all appear to work, but I am still struggling with which one feels “right”.  Right now my gut is going with a mix with the binding and returning strings.  As I could see myself extending the binding to handle input with jQuery UI datepicker controls.

*Is there an accepted practice when handling displaying dates or other types such as currency? Is there another option I am missing that solves this problem?*

Comment: I use strings in my projects. The model binder can parse a date from a string so I can round trip values easily that way.

Comment: I have posted my json net result to the same problem, it converts the date to iso format making it much easier to work with.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778599/knockout-dates-being-reset-on-post-to-mvc-controller/15799992#15799992

Comment: Using momentjs is the best ways to deal with dates, see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I think the [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) solution is the best simply because it imposes less on the client.  All the other solutions require additional client parsing or additional client code.

I have switched over to using JSON.NET for all of my ASP .NET code that uses JSON because its a much more customizable library.

For example I have had to implement JSON data in MVC that conformed to [Google's Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable_toJSON) (used in combination with Knockout for paging, etc.) and the default `JavascriptSerializer` simply cannot do it.

In addition with JSON.NET you can customize it to actually spit out full Knockout view models so you don't even need to employ the mapping plugin.

I wrote a sample library called [FluentJson.NET](https://github.com/paultyng/FluentJson.NET) which lets you do things in Razor like:

```
var viewModel = @JsonObject.Create()
    .AddProperty("name", "value")
    .AddObservable("knockoutProperty", 123)
```

And get:

```
var viewModel = {"name":"value","knockoutProperty":ko.observable(123)}
```

So you can get a Knockout view model without any client side hoops to jump through.

You could easily extend something like that to handle date values however you would prefer.

Comment: Interesting nuget project, I will certainly check it out.

Comment: I replaced my Json.Encode(Model) to the JSON.NET JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) for this exact reason. Works like a charm and I didn't have to write a single other line of code. Nice tip I've been searching for this all day.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest a middle man approach through  `ko.mapping.fromJS( data, mapping )` this would allow you to customize even with a user defined object.

```
var $data = { _ID : '1', _Created : someDate };  
var $mapping = {
    '_Created' : {
       update: function (options) {
           return convertdata( options.data );
       }
    }
}
var viewDataModel = ko.mapping( data, mapping );  
ko.applyBindings( viewDataModel );
```

mapping parameter allows you handle changes easily and can easily be leveraged with arrays also.

Comment: Best solution : 1- no additional libraries to add to your project. 2- your code does not traverse all fields; it directly updates the fields you specify.
Only one problem here is input fields really need formatted strings.

Answer (score 5):

The better way to handle dates in knockoutjs is to use moment library and handle dates like boss.
You can easily deal with dates like /Date(-62135578800000)/. No need to bother of how your serialize date in controller.

**Approach 1 : Directly in view:**

Lets say your knockout model gets such date in a observable called sentDate and now it has value /Date(-62135578800000)/. To bind it in view you can do :

```
<p><label>Date</label>: <span data-bind="moment(sentDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')"></span></p>
```

**Approach 2 : In custom binding**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var jsonDate = valueAccessor();     
        var ret = moment(jsonDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        element.innerHTML = ret;
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

    }
};
```

Usage same as you had said :

```
<td data-bind="date: sentDate">
</td>
```

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) supports lots of date time formats and utility functions on dates.

Comment: Tnx ajay, it moment js saved my day, i like the Approach 1 easy method

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code to generate short date strings.  I use it for my date strings and jQueryUi Date Picker.

```
class T
    {
        public DateTime d { get; set; }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var k = new T { d = DateTime.Now };

        var formatter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
        formatter.DateTimeFormat = "d";
        var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(k, formatter);
    }
```

This generates the following JSON

```
"{"d":"4/21/2012"}"
```

This results clean JavaScript code for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just came up on this question because we also started using knockout.js on our MVC3 app.
Since we already have jQuery datepicker and we need to format dates differently by locale (portal has different languages and different formats are presented per language), so maybe this mashup of technological requirements arise somewhere else and will be useful:

```
var jsDateFormat = "@CultureHelper.JsDateFormat"; // can be something like yy-mm-dd

//...

 ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (value != null) {
            var jsonDate = new Date(parseInt(valueAccessor().substr(6)));
            element.innerHTML = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(jsDateFormat, jsonDate);
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    }
};
```

And in the view then for example:

```
<p><label>Date</label>: <span data-bind="date: SentDate"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner alternative to @photo_tom's answer is to decorate the property with the IsoDateTimeConverter via the JsonConverter attribute, like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I loved Andres Toro's answer except that in my case, input fields are expecting formatted strings.  So I am using JQuery to format my dates according to my favorite format provided by my helper `@Html.ConvertDateFormat()`
Hope this helps someone day.

```
var mapping = {
    'ActualDateTime': {
        update: function (options) {
            var d = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(options.data);
            return (d) ? $.datepicker.formatDate('@Html.ConvertDateFormat()', new Date(+d[1])) : value;
            //return "5/10/2017";
        }
    }
};
var paymentModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(modelJSON, mapping);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use a data converter instead of sending data directly to server to fix any client encoding or parsing issues, without the need to use additional tools.

In the Knockout JS view model file, I add the following code before the view model setup, which intercept selected proeprries of the view model and use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to take care of date convertions:

```
// converting data before sending to controller
var dataConverter = function (key, value) {  
    if (key === 'InvoiceDate') {
        return moment(value).format("YYYY MMMM DD");
    }

    return value;
};
```

Then I use the `dataConverter` instead of `data` in the ajax save method within the view model:

```
// Example view model for sales invoice
SalesInvoiceViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.SaveInvoice = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SalesInvoices/SaveInvoice/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.toJSON(self, **dataConverter**),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.invoiceViewModel !== null) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.invoiceViewModel, {}, self);
                }
                if (data.redirectToLocation !== null) {
                    window.location = data.redirectToLocation;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // report error to user
            }
        });
    }
```