# ASP.Net WebMethod fails because ko.toJSON() produces different results for DateTime.MinValue

Tags: asp.net, json, internet-explorer, knockout.js, webmethod

I'm getting an error when I call my WebMethod due to the Date format. I have a Date equal to DateTime.MinValue.

calling...

```
ko.toJSON({ employee: viewModel.employee });

[WebMethod]
public static string SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
{

}
```

I get the following results...

```
Chrome (works):
"terminationDate":"0001-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"

IE8 (does not work):
"terminationDate":"1-01-01T06:00:00Z"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942789/in-knockoutjs-does-ko-tojson-work-with-dates

Comment: I'd rather not add extra observables that don't map to the object on the server. This is my fix: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON({ employee: viewModel.employee })).replace(/\"1-01-01/g, "\"0001-01-01"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by padding the dates in my JSON:

```
var postData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(viewModel)).replace(/\"1-01-01/g, "\"0001-01-01"));
```